# Get photos from specific album Facebook SDK

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, photos

I am using latest iOS Facebook sdk. I obtained the albums, so I have the ID's. Can't figure out how to get the photos from a specific album o f the user's.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album

Answer (score 0):

Try following FQL

```
SELECT src_big, comment_info,  object_id, src_small, owner, caption, created, like_info FROM photo WHERE album_object_id  IN (SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner = me() )
```